# Is there a GPU Architecture simulator that supports Kepler?

Tags: gpgpu, simulator, kepler

I am looking "GPGPU-sim"-like simulator that supports Kepler architecture.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I did not find any simulator to simulate Kepler architecture. there is no update for GPGPU-Sim for many years, maybe the developers have graduated, so If you want to simulate the kepler architecture, it is better to add some code by yourself.
It is better if someone has finished this job and he/she like to share to the public.